# Svelte `unexpected character '#'` when using an if block

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I'm trying to conditionally display information inside a `<textarea>` like this :

```
<script>
  let name = 'world';
</script>

<textarea>
  {#if name}{name}{/if}
</textarea>
```

This throws `Unexpected character '#'` when compiling.

What is happening here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use svelte syntax inside `input` elements.

What will work:

```
<script>
  let name = 'world';
</script>

{#if name}
    <textarea>
        {name}
    </textarea>
{/if}
```

or:

```
<textarea bind:value={name} />
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why there is this limitation, is it a bug ? A fool-barrier to avoid bad patterns ? etc...